# Rest Http Status code for Match and Non Matching of the Data

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'm building an application with a REST-based API and have come to the point where i'm specifying status codes for each requests.

My scenario is "verification of the biometrics send by the client with the data available in the database"

What status code should i send for requests failing verification of the biometrics (NOT Matching) ?

If biometrics matches with the database  , 
in this case i am returning Http status code 200.

If biometrics Not Matches with the database send by client ,
in this case i am looking for the appropriate http status code ?

i found status code 422 is appropriate ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you using biometric data for authentication? If so then 401 otherwise 200 OK with Error Message

Comment: If you are using biometric data for authentication then you should use 401 for failed - as it means Not authorized. In company where I work, we use 412 Precondition Failed for these type of scenarios.  There is also possibility to send 200 status code and have property status and error.. status is either true or false  and error is filled when status is false (so i.e: you would have status:false and error: biometrics not matched

Comment: User first logged into application using username, password and OTP then user registers the biometrics after registration he/she cross verifies the data as stored correctly or not.in this case in am verifiying the biometrics

Comment: @vanillaSugar [412](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?rfc=7232#section-4.2) should only be used with conditional requests as specified in [RFC 7232](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?rfc=7232), i.e. the request sends an additionel `ETag` or `If-Match` or the like header. The question here is actually is, IMO, if a validation check is really meant to be a client error or just a business logic decision. In the latter case not a 400-ish error could should be returned but a media type describing the outcome. IMO there is now right or wrong and thus primarily opinionated

Comment: is okay to use 409 Conflict ? Need suggestions ?

Comment: [409](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?rfc=7231#section-6.5.8) states that it should be used to indicate a conflict with the current state of the target resource. It should be used if the client is able to resolve the conflict manually and resubmit the request. In terms of your validation this is more or less unlikely. As mentioned before I doubt that a business logic "failure" maps well here to a HTTP status error per se hence my advice to use a media type describing the validation success rather then trying to perform a balancing act here